# Using Scanner to print both token and delimeter value

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this -

```
"fruit=apple man=human abc=123"
```

I want values to be printed like -

```
fruit=
apple
man=
human
abc=
123
```

i.e. I also want to see the delimeter values. Currently I'm trying-

```
String status2="fruit=apple man=human abc=123";
Scanner scn = new Scanner(status2).useDelimiter("[a-z]*=+");
while(scn.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(scn.next());
    System.out.println(scn.delimiter());
}
```

But I cannot see the delimeter values

```
apple 
[a-z]*=+
human 
[a-z]*=+
123
[a-z]*=+
```

**Updated String -**

```
"cobdate=01/28/2013 fundsnotextracted= elapsedtime=00:06:02 user=dataprod starttime=Wed, 30 Jan 2013 11:50:30 periods=DAILY, MTD, YTD knowledgedate=01/30/2013:11:50:10 progress=67 statusstep=Generating Reports ....."
```

**Expected output -**

```
cobdate=01/28/2013 
fundsnotextracted= 
elapsedtime=00:06:02 
user=dataprod 
starttime=Wed, 30 Jan 2013 11:50:30 
periods=DAILY, MTD, YTD 
knowledgedate=01/30/2013:11:50:10 
progress=67 
statusstep=Generating Reports .....
```

Comment: Any reason you're not just using String.split(token)?

Comment: Yes, because sometimes parameter values can be null, i.e fruit= man=human. Also the parameter positions are not fixed.

Comment: Split twice.  Once on whitespace, once on "=".  An array of size 1 means that there is no value for a given parameter.

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: @RohitJain Added the expected output

Comment: @kaustavdatta.. Will your keys ever contain whitespaces?

Comment: @RohitJain its safe to assume No.. but it would be nice to use a generic code.

Comment: @kaustavdatta.. However, I've updated the code considering keys don't contain whitespace. You better satisfy this condition somehow. Life would be easy. ;) ;)

Comment: @RohitJain thnks a lot for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiter is not correct. You should set your delimiter after each `=` sign, and also at every `whitespace`. You can use this insead: -

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(status2).useDelimiter("(?<==)|[ ]");
```

Here the delimiter is: - empty string following every `=` denoted by `(?<==)` or a whitespace denoted by `[ ]`.

---

However, given your input string, and the required output, I would rather `split` the string, with the same `pattern` as I used in the `delimiter`, which will give you an array, that you can also use somewhere else later on: -

```
String status2="fruit=apple man=human abc=123";
String[] arr = status2.split("(?<==)|[ ]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

---

**Update: -**

For your updated input, you would have to do some more work. First of all, you strictly need a `split` here. Plus, you would have to do the split twice - once on a whitespace, and another on a `=`.

Now, your whitespace must be followed by a sequence of alphabets ending with `=`, so that you don't mistakenly split on the whitespace contained in the values. So, your code should look like this: -

```
String str = "cobdate=01/28/2013 fundsnotextracted= elapsedtime=00:06:02 user=dataprod starttime=Wed, 30 Jan 2013 11:50:30 periods=DAILY, MTD, YTD knowledgedate=01/30/2013:11:50:10 progress=67 statusstep=Generating Reports .....";

// Split on a whitespace, followed by a sequence of letters ending with =.
// This ensures that you don't split on whitespace, optionally present in some values
String[] arr = str.split("[ ](?=[a-zA-Z]+=)");

for (String eachString : arr) {
    // Split on empty string following the = sign
    String[] tempArr = eachString.split("(?<==)");

    System.out.print(tempArr[0] + " ");

    // To ensure that you don't print a non-existence value.
    if (tempArr.length == 2) {
        System.out.println(tempArr[1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

**Output: -**

```
cobdate= 01/28/2013
fundsnotextracted= 
elapsedtime= 00:06:02
user= dataprod
starttime= Wed, 30 Jan 2013 11:50:30
periods= DAILY, MTD, YTD
knowledgedate= 01/30/2013:11:50:10
progress= 67
statusstep= Generating Reports ....
```

Comment: I'm updating my string. It doesnt seem to work on my actual String